# PageIndexChanging in GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, page-index-changed

I have a gridview which I am using to display a dataset result.
The problem is I am using paging in it. But when I click on the page # it says that I haven't handled the event. Do I need to rebind the dataset???

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
protected void grdView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    FillGrid();
    grdView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works... I didn't know this pageindex incrementing before.

Comment: `Viewstate` should be preferred to avoid excessive db calls on page Change events

Answer (score 4):

Try it

In the pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        loadGrid();
    }
}
```

In the pageindexchanging

```
private void loadGrid()
{
    using (your_bankEntities context = new your_bankEntities()) //use your connection .edmx
    {
        var jmDados = (from jm in context.yourdbo  orderby jm.your fieldkey  
                         select new
                           {
                               jm.Field1,
                               jm.Field2,
                               jm.Field3,
                               jm.Field4,
                               ........ 
                               jm.n

                           }).ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = jmDados;

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

In the pageindexchanging

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

loadGrid();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the .PageIndex before binding data! Otherwise, you would need extra clicks which actually **double** the BindData method calls. The following is my tested vb code.

```
Private Sub GridViewL_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridViewL.PageIndexChanging

    GridViewL.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    BindData()  ' your method to bind data to the grid
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net, it does not have much difference with C#, you just remove the semicolons at the end of each line

```
Private Sub myGridview_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles myGridview.PageIndexChanging

   LoadGridView() //Call your method to load the data into the grid.
   myGridview.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
   myGridview.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, keep in mind that changing the page also fires the `OnRowCommand` event, with `CommandName` "Page". Be careful not to put conflicting code in that method, that could be altering the result of your `OnPageIndexChanging` actions.